# Spy on ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges

Tags: angular

I'm trying to test that a component calls `detectChanges` on it's injected `ChangeDetectorRef`

I've stepped through the code and it's definitely called, but it appears I'm getting different values for the ChangeDetectorRef in the component and in the test.  Here's the code.  I've also tried the commented out spy, but it didn't work either.

```
it('should call ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges from onFixedUpdate', () => {
    let changeDetectorService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ChangeDetectorRef, null);
    let spy = spyOn(changeDetectorService, 'detectChanges').and.callThrough();
    //let spy = spyOn(fixture.changeDetectorRef, 'detectChanges').and.callThrough();

    expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    fixture.componentInstance.onFixedUpdate(1);

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: I'm having this same problem.  It's as if we don't have access to the instance of the ChangeDetectorRef service.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2: How to mock ChangeDetectorRef while unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421807/angular-2-how-to-mock-changedetectorref-while-unit-testing)

Answer (score 11):

First some considerations:

1. `ChangeDetectorRef` is not provided through DI, so you cannot provide a double.
2. `fixture.changeDetectorRef` is not the same as the component provided, so you cannot use this.
3. `fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ChangeDetectorRef)` will create a new instance of the private class `ViewRef` (the public class `ViewRef` is just an alias for `ViewRef$1`), every time it is invoked, then the object provided to the component is another.

So my solution is:

```
// Get a reference to an instance of the private class
const changeDetectorRef = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ChangeDetectorRef);
// spy on private class prototype
const detectChangesSpy = spyOn(changeDetectorRef.constructor.prototype, 'detectChanges');
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume, inside your component, you've named the injected `ChangeDetectorRef` as `cdr`.

```
it('should call ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges from onFixedUpdate', () => {

   // grab the the reference to the ChangeDetectorRef (cdr) directly from the component
   let spy = spyOn((<any>fixture.componentInstance).cdr, 'detectChanges').and.callThrough();

   expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

   fixture.componentInstance.onFixedUpdate(1);

   expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and used the technique described in [Juan's answer to a similar SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44269677/3789972)

The basic gist is to spy directly on the property in your component to which the injected `ChangeDetectorRef` is assigned. If you have marked this property as private, which is often the case, there is a workaround by casting the component to `any` and then using that to create the spy on the private property.

Please note I would have simply added this as a comment but I do not have high enough rep - I hope this is ok!