# Angular 2 - Test component with ChangeDetectorRef dependency

Tags: angular, angular-test

i'm trying to testing a component with ChangeDetectorRef

```
constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

And this is the spec file

```
import {RTLateralMenuComponent} from "./RTLateralMenu.component";

describe('RTLateralMenuComponent', () => {
  let app: RTLateralMenuComponent;

  beforeEach(()=>{
    app = new RTLateralMenuComponent();
  });
});
```

new RTLateralMenuComponent obviously expect an argument, but i don't how it works.

Comment: Please read angular unit test guide. You will get to know better ways to do it https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-test-basics

Comment: I started to read the guide, but this error appears immediately

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2: How to mock ChangeDetectorRef while unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421807/angular-2-how-to-mock-changedetectorref-while-unit-testing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mock it

```
const cdRefMock = {
  detectChanges: () => null
};

app = new RTLateralMenuComponent(cdRefMock);
```

You will have to implement every method used in your component : `detectChanges` being the most common one, I thought I would give it right away.

(PS : I assumed you don't use the testbed since you're creating an instance of your component)

Comment: The following error appears: ''Property markforcheck is missing in type { detectChanges: () => null }".

Comment: Then add `markforcheck` in your mock. I told you to put every method you use in your mock.

Comment: No problem, I'm here for that !